# How to prettify / beautify wiki markup?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia

Mediawiki markup can be very hard to understand, especially in old and complex templates in Wikipedia projects. A prettifier/beautifier would help, but I can't find any. Does anything like this exist?

Answer (score 1):

The best you can have is syntax highlight (check [Extension:CodeMirror](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CodeMirror) for instance). Problem with mediawiki syntax is that line feeds are interpreted and may change the layout of the rendering.

Comment: Thanks, syntax highlight is quite helpful. AFAIK sometimes line feeds can be ignored, so I thought prettifier would exist. But looks like it doesn't :(

Answer (score 0):

I use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Cacycle/wikEd which can be copied to other wikis